# How do I use Apache mod_rewrite > to redirect a Subdirectory to a Domain (On a Subdomain)?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting, subdirectory

**I have a site on a staging subdomain:**
*http://sd1.domain1.com/subdir/category-1/*

Where 'subdir' is the subdirectory where I'm holding open source (let's say WordPress) files.

**The URL that I want on staging should be:**
*http://sd1.domain1.com/category-1/*

What the Final URL should be once I migrate everything from my subdomain to the client's domain:
www.domain2.com/category-1/

So, essentially what I need is the Regular Expression to use in my .htaccess file.

It needs to:

1. remove the 'subdir' subdirectory from the URL
2. work on a subdomain (without the '.com')
3. work on a production domain (with the '.com'
4. work with and without SSL (https:// + http://)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's WordPress,

```
RewriteRule .* subdir/index.php [L]
```

You don't have to write anything for requirements `2`, `3`, `4`. You're rewriting request URIs, the host and protocol are unexamined and unchanged.

If it's not WordPress, then you might need to do something different.